# What's a good "todo" widget for Mac OS X 10.6?

Tags: macos, ical

I'm considering small widgets like QuickCal, Anxiety, DoBeDo, etc.  Integration with Mail/iCal would be great.  What's your favorite?

Answer (score 2):

Lately, I've became really passionate about [Alarms](http://www.mediaatelier.com/Alarms/).

It transforms your entire menu bar into a drop-area for whatever file, email, shortcut you want to handle later.

Plus, it syncs with iCal, so you may use it in combination with another full-featured app (like [TheHitList](http://www.potionfactory.com/thehitlist/)).

Just watch the introductory video!

Answer (score 1):

I use [Anxiety](http://www.anxietyapp.com/) and its great, cause I really don't need much except remembering the name of the things I need to do. 
I've also tried [iProcrastinate](http://www.iprocrastinateapp.com/mac/), and its quite good (but too complex for me, I needed something fast, simple and unobtrusive, Anxiety!), but it doesn't sync to iCal, which is a downside.
Things I've heard is great! Although again, quite a bit like iProcrastinate: not a widget or simple ToDo, but a full featured app.

So to my liking, Anxiety for the desktop and DoBeDo for the Dashboard. You can have both really, and because they sync with iCal they will work great together.

Hope it helps!
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

I've heard great things about [Things](http://culturedcode.com/things/), but I haven't used it myself.

It's a bit more than a widget, but it does To-Dos. It's got iCal integration, and I think it does Mail too.

iPhone version available (with sync).

Answer (score 0):

[MenuCalendarClock](http://www.objectpark.net/mcc.html) for iCal runs on the menu bar displays your iCal Todos and upcoming events.

Answer (score 0):

[Things](http://culturedcode.com/things/) - Simply amazing and easy to use for To-Do's, projects, small notes to self. And full integration with Mac and iOS - A bit costly, but it does the job with perfection.